# Running `supabase link` by itself neither works not provides a helpful error message

Tags: command-line-interface, supabase

[I solved this problem, but the answer was weirdly elusive, buried in [this blog post](https://supabase.com/blog/supabase-cli-v1-and-admin-api-beta)]

Going through this guide on Supabase: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-nextjs?database-method=dashboard&language=ts#set-up-the-database-schema

There's instructions to use `supabase link` and then `supabase db pull`, but running the former on its own yields:

```
required flag(s) "project-ref" not set
Try rerunning the command with --debug to troubleshoot the error.
```

What is meant by `--project-ref` exactly and how is this flag actually used?

I looked through the docs on Supabase and Github and found nothing. Even in the guide I linked, there's not detail on the flag; this should be updated so the guide can be used properly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: https://supabase.com/blog/supabase-cli-v1-and-admin-api-beta

`supabase link --project-ref <project-id>`

Simple as that, yet excluded from the guide, Github, proper documentation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, we'll get the docs updated shortly. It's likely this has changed in the CLI from how it originally was working before.